# Способ задания размера <img> в отзывчивой верстке

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Для оптимизации скорости загрузки страницы рекомендуют указывать размеры  в HTML. Как быть в случае отзывчивой верстки?

Comment: Это не для оптимизации скорости загрузки, а чтобы строя структуру сайта на основе одного лишь html, пока css еще загрузился бразузер правильно выстроил положение элементов страницы, чтобы когда css загрузится пользователь не заметил скачкообразного изменения позиций всех элементов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно примерно так:

```css
.img-container{
  /*любые 'отзывчивые' стили*/
  width:calc(10vw + 100px);
  height:20vh;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'img-container'>
  <img src = './imgSrc' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не пройдет валидацию.

Comment: "In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels."